# Unable to delete data from multiple databases using multithreading in spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am currently working over database operations to delete data over different database.
I want to run parallel threads in `Spring JPA` to delete data in different databases.I am able to it sequentially.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, readOnly = false)

public void changeAmt() {

//routing db for thread

Query query = (Query)entityManager.createNamedQuery("update_payment_card");
    recordCount=query.executeUpdate();

}
```

I have observed that whenever there is call to this function spring gets the `DB` connection using `transactionInterceptor`

so every time a thread call this method the underlying  db connection changes.

hence only one db get effected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use a connection pool, the connection object reference might differ between successive calls, because the pool will serve you the next available cached connection.

> so every time a thread call this method the underlying db connection
>   changes.
>
> hence only one db get effected.

You usually have one DataSource configured for one DB schema. But multiple concurrent requests may use multiple connections to this data source. If you use multiple data bases, you should have multiple Data Sources and you might use JTA to have a global transaction that spans across multiple data sources.

Comment: thanks  for the reply, connection changes means e.g one thread enters the method it get connection for a particular Db and when another thread enter that method previously acquired Db connection get override with new Db connection hence only last connection works...

As my transaction are independent for multiple Db I cannot use JTa ..i.e operation on one Db table is not related to other Db table...

Comment: Databases are built to run concurrently, like JDBC drivers and connection pools. You can have multiple threads executing this method, each one running isolated of the others.

Comment: yes it should run in isolated but  that is not happening ...connection of one thread get override when other thread get connection any reason for that?